# How to add txt files to windows search index programatically

Tags: c#, windows, search, service

I am looking for a way to add txt file type to content indexing of windows search problematically in C#.
Note I don't want to add individual txt files by using file.setattribute. I want to check the index properties and file content for txt filetype problematically.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
 string _Path = Path.GetFullPath(mPath);
            Uri path = new Uri(_Path);
            string indexingPath = path.AbsoluteUri;
            CSearchManager csm = new CSearchManager();
            CSearchCrawlScopeManager manager = csm.GetCatalog("SystemIndex").GetCrawlScopeManager();

            if (manager.IncludedInCrawlScope(indexingPath) == 0)
            {
                manager.AddUserScopeRule(indexingPath, 1, 1, 0);
                //add files and folders to content index
                DirectoryInfo dinfos = new DirectoryInfo(_Path);
                var targetFiles = dinfos.EnumerateFiles("*.txt");
                File.SetAttributes(medicalDicPath, (File.GetAttributes(_Path) & ~FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed));
                Parallel.ForEach(targetFiles, targetFile => { File.SetAttributes(targetFile.FullName, (File.GetAttributes(targetFile.FullName) & ~FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed)); });
                manager.SaveAll();
            }
```